# Return the difference between two datetime expressions

Tags: mysql, sql-update

On my MySQL table I need check if the **TIMEDIFF()** between two rows is greater than the value three minutes

If the **TIMEDIFF()** is **less** I update the columns **xDisabled** with 1 value

This is my table

```
+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| xID  | xDate_xHourMinute   | xLines  | xDisabled |
+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 1405 | 2020-06-21 05:24:19 | 3018122 |           |
| 1424 | 2020-06-21 05:22:53 | 3018122 |           |
| 1462 | 2020-06-21 05:22:03 | 3018122 |           |
| 1473 | 2020-06-21 05:18:59 | 3018122 |           |
| 1481 | 2020-06-21 05:18:03 | 3018122 |           |
+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
5 rows in set
```

I have tried without success this sql query because all rows on the table are updated

```
UPDATE `xMinutesSet` a
JOIN `xMinutesSet` b ON a.xLines = B.xLines
AND TIMEDIFF(
    a.xDate_xHourMinute,
    b.xDate_xHourMinute
) < 3
SET a.xDisabled = 1;


+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| xID  | xDate_xHourMinute   | xLines  | xDisabled |
+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 1405 | 2020-06-21 05:24:19 | 3018122 |         1 |
| 1424 | 2020-06-21 05:22:53 | 3018122 |         1 |
| 1462 | 2020-06-21 05:22:03 | 3018122 |         1 |
| 1473 | 2020-06-21 05:18:59 | 3018122 |         1 |
| 1481 | 2020-06-21 05:18:03 | 3018122 |         1 |
+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
5 rows in set
```

I need this return

```
+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| xID  | xDate_xHourMinute   | xLines  | xDisabled |
+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 1405 | 2020-06-21 05:24:19 | 3018122 |         1 | 00:01:26
| 1424 | 2020-06-21 05:22:53 | 3018122 |         1 | 00:00:50 
| 1462 | 2020-06-21 05:22:03 | 3018122 |           | 00:03:04
| 1473 | 2020-06-21 05:18:59 | 3018122 |         1 | 00:00:56
| 1481 | 2020-06-21 05:18:03 | 3018122 |           |
+------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
5 rows in set
```

How to do resolve this?
Please, any suggestion

My table below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xminutesset`;
CREATE TABLE `xminutesset` (
  `xID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `xDate_xHourMinute` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `xLines` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xDisabled` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`xID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of xminutesset
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `xminutesset` VALUES ('1405', '2020-06-21 05:24:19', '3018122', null);
INSERT INTO `xminutesset` VALUES ('1424', '2020-06-21 05:22:53', '3018122', null);
INSERT INTO `xminutesset` VALUES ('1462', '2020-06-21 05:22:03', '3018122', null);
INSERT INTO `xminutesset` VALUES ('1473', '2020-06-21 05:18:59', '3018122', null);
INSERT INTO `xminutesset` VALUES ('1481', '2020-06-21 05:18:03', '3018122', null);
```

Comment: What is your version of Mysql?

Comment: note that the output of `TIMEDIFF()` can be negative, checking for `TIMEDIFF()<3` seems not OK.

Comment: @forpas in local the version of MySQL is 8.0.17, in hosting is 5.5.62. i need solution for both versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LAG()` window function in MySql 8.0 and `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` instead of `TIMEDIFF()`:

```
UPDATE `xminutesset` a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *,   
    LAG(xDate_xHourMinute) OVER (PARTITION BY xLines ORDER BY xDate_xHourMinute) prev
  FROM `xminutesset`
) b 
ON a.xID = b.xID
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, b.prev, b.xDate_xHourMinute) < 3
SET a.xDisabled = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gbnWno65SdqDqBnu5ijGnK/1).

This will work for previous versions:

```
UPDATE `xminutesset` a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT x.*,
    (
      SELECT MAX(xDate_xHourMinute)
      FROM `xminutesset`
      WHERE `xLines` = x.`xLines` AND xDate_xHourMinute < x.xDate_xHourMinute 
    ) prev
  FROM `xminutesset` x
) b 
ON a.xID = b.xID
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, b.prev, b.xDate_xHourMinute) < 3
SET a.xDisabled = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gbnWno65SdqDqBnu5ijGnK/3).

Results:

```
| xID  | xDate_xHourMinute   | xLines  | xDisabled |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1405 | 2020-06-21 05:24:19 | 3018122 | 1         |
| 1424 | 2020-06-21 05:22:53 | 3018122 | 1         |
| 1462 | 2020-06-21 05:22:03 | 3018122 |           |
| 1473 | 2020-06-21 05:18:59 | 3018122 | 1         |
| 1481 | 2020-06-21 05:18:03 | 3018122 |           |
```

Comment: thanks but not working on the version of MySQL 5.5.62

Comment: See my 2nd query.